# In MySQL when we do forward engineer this error is occurred

Tags: mysql

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_city_state1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`state_idstate`)
    REFERENC...' at line 9
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`city`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`city` (
          `idcity` INT NOT NULL,
          `city_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `state_idstate` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idcity`),
          INDEX `fk_city_state1_idx` (`state_idstate` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_city_state1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`state_idstate`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`state_tab` (`idstate`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. It will probably tell you (and us) that the problem is at the "visible", not at the constraint. Also please note if you are (not) using MySQL 8.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.